# IIS process with WCF crashing randomly

Tags: wcf, iis, crash

Need help debugging why server crashing. IIS Server on Win 2008, CPU load normal, Memory usage log, nothing seems wrong.

Randomly w3p process crashes. In event log I see first:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll, version: 4.0.30319.18044, time stamp: 0x51271348
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000091ac6
Faulting process id: 0x1928
Faulting application start time: 0x01ceaf1919acdfd4
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Runteb92aa12#\9a8ecadcc9e05f435158bedc1f1a3e74\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll
Report Id: 5beef11c-1b0c-11e3-8eec-0026b9347fe0
```

And then I see:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.18052, time stamp: 0x5173c114
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x00000000000055a7
Faulting process id: 0x1760
Faulting application start time: 0x01ceaf191e746321
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 60deebcd-1b0c-11e3-8eec-0026b9347fe0
```

And then:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.18052, time stamp: 0x5173c114
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000073dc4
Faulting process id: 0x2208
Faulting application start time: 0x01ceaf193c19060b
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 7e58b5f2-1b0c-11e3-8eec-0026b9347fe0
```

After that application pool goes into stopped state.

All webservice exceptions handled, I have no idea where to look. System can be stable for a long time (days) and then just randomly crash.

Is there any way to get to root cause of such problem?

Is there any way to monitor service and restart in case of such crash inside IIS?

EDIT:

Got more details. Debug diagnostics tool was able to read memory dump. Seems like WCF call causing it. Looks like when I create instance of WCF service and it starts to deserialize message it goes into infinite loop. Any ideas on how to get BETTER details on what's going on? In this stack I don't see any of my code. I cut middle portion out, it's just repeating calls in serialization DLL

```
Process Image   c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe 
System Up-Time   21 day(s) 11:44:13 
Process Up-Time   1 day(s) 19:43:33 

Thread 49 - System ID 1104

.NET Call Stack

Full Call Stack

Function     Arg 1     Arg 2     Arg 3     Arg 4   Source 
clr!GetRuntimeAssemblyHelper+1d     000007fe`f9cc471c     00000000`024dd240     00000000`ffba5cb0     00000000`00000000    
clr!RuntimeTypeHandle::GetAssembly+8c     00000000`ffba5cb0     00000003`00053d30     000007fe`f87bd608     00000000`ffd338a8    
mscorlib_ni+4ec579     00000004`0313e578     00000004`015e1ef0     00000001`fff8f2c0     000007fe`f1ee8f0e    
mscorlib_ni+4f0a39     00000004`0313e578     000007fe`f1ed0af3     00000001`ffbbb300     00000004`0313e5a0    
0x000007fe`9ad39c8a     00000000`ffd32520     000007fe`f9c6c4c5     00000000`0000008b     00000000`00000000    
0x000007fe`9b6e2976     00000000`ffd32520     00000000`000054e2     00000000`00000000     000007fe`f1ec2e00    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b2ce1     00000004`015e1ef0     00000003`00023dc0     00000000`0e656548     00000000`0e6564e8    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b29ed     00000002`030caad8     00000001`00b65cc8     00000001`ffc11890     000007fe`f8e31860    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c91f     00000000`00000066     00000000`00000000     00000004`015e1f98     00000003`00023dc0    
0x000007fe`9bda513d     00000001`ffc25548     00000000`000054e1     00000000`00000000     000007fe`f1ec2e00    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b2ce1     00000004`015e1ef0     00000003`00023dc0     00000004`0313e578     00000003`00023dc0    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b29ed     00000002`030cbe08     000007fe`f203bb28     00000003`ffe868e8     000007fe`f8e31860    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c91f     00000003`ffe86520     000007fe`9ab63858     00000000`00000147     00000004`ffb5afb0    
0x000007fe`9bda4ef9     00000003`ffe86520     00000004`0313e5a0     00000000`00000000     00000003`00083558    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b08c1     00000002`030cbcf0     000007fe`f213c7cd     00000002`030c7c20     00000002`030c7c40    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b29ed     00000004`003e33f0     00000002`030c7c40     00000003`00083558     000007fe`f8e31860    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c91f     00000001`ffc1eaa0     00000004`015e2018     00000004`015e2264     00000004`015e2080    
0x000007fe`9bda4687     00000001`ffc1eaa0     00000000`000054dc     00000000`00000000     000007fe`f1ec2e00    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b2ce1     00000004`015e1ef0     00000003`00023dc0     00000004`0313e578     00000003`00023dc0    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b29ed     00000002`018a8af0     000007fe`f203bb28     00000003`ffe85768     000007fe`f8e31860    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c91f 

.....

0x000007fe`9b8e780b     00000001`ffcb8690     00000000`00000016     00000000`00000000     000007fe`f1ec2e00    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b2ce1     00000004`015e1ef0     00000003`00023dc0     00000003`028539a0     000007fe`9a97d658    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b29ed     00000001`ffc22190     00000003`028539c0     00000003`000837c0     000007fe`f8e31860    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c91f     00000001`ffc1eaa0     000007fe`f213d7a0     00000003`00052e00     00000004`015e2018    
0x000007fe`9bda44cf     00000001`ffc1eaa0     000007fe`f1edf4fc     00000000`0e6cc8e0     00000000`00000000    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b2ce1     00000001`ffc1eaf0     000007fe`f9cf5c2f     00000000`ffba5b60     00000000`00000000    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c45b     00000004`015e2018     00000004`015e2018     00000000`00000011     000007fe`f1ee5e19    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c766     00000004`015e1ef0     00000003`00023dc0     00000001`ffbbb3f0     00000000`00000007    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+30a177     00000004`0313e578     00000004`0313e5a0     00000001`fff8ac40     000007fe`f8e31860    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c91f     00000001`ffbbaec8     000007fe`9ab625a8     80000000`00000000     000007fe`f860d2a2    
0x000007fe`9b6e1823     00000001`fff8a948     000007fe`f2035929     00000000`0e6ccbd0     00000000`00000000    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b08c1     00000001`fff8a990     00000000`00000000     00000001`ffbe0180     00000001`ffbbae00    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c45b     00000004`015e2018     000007fe`f821e740     00000000`00000010     000007fe`f1ee5e19    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c766     00000004`015e1ef0     00000003`00023dc0     00000001`ffdadf58     000007fe`f86157d7    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+30a177     00000001`fff7d2f0     000007fe`f1ee8efa     00000001`ffdb1d68     000007fe`f8e31860    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c91f     00000001`ffdafc80     00000004`0313e5e8     00000000`00000000     000007fe`f1edf848    
0x000007fe`9b6e0d8c     00000001`ffdafc80     000007fe`f1edf4fc     00000000`0e6cced0     00000000`00000000    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b2ce1     00000001`ffdafcd0     000007fe`f9cf5c2f     00000003`ffc3f3a8     00000004`0313e500    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c45b     00000004`015e2018     000007fe`f821e740     00000000`00000005     000007fe`f1ee5e19    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c766     00000004`015e1ef0     00000003`00023dc0     02261db5`f87be0c0     000007fe`f9c6797c    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+30a177     000007fe`9ac3c088     000007fe`fa074137     00000001`ffdac0f8     000007fe`f8e31860    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c91f     00000004`0313cee0     00000001`ffdac0f8     00000004`0313e578     00000000`0e6cd220    
0x000007fe`9a85a630     00000001`ffdab308     000007fe`f2035900     00000000`0e6cd1c0     000007fe`f1edf484    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b2ce1     00000001`ffdab358     000007fe`f1ee7149     00000004`015e1f20     00000000`00000004    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+308197     00000004`015e1ef0     00000003`00023dc0     00000004`0313e578     00000003`00023dc0    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b29ed     00000004`0313cf38     000007fe`f203bb28     00000001`ffda1c40     000007fe`f8e31860    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c91f     00000004`015e1f98     000007fe`9b01bda0     00000001`ffbbb3f0     00000000`00000003    
0x000007fe`9a85a430     00000001`ffda1938     00000000`00000003     00000000`00000000     000007fe`f1ec2e00    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b08c1     00000004`015e1ef0     00000003`00023dc0     00000004`015e1ef0     000007fe`f20879f9    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b29ed     000007fe`9ac3bf38     000007fe`fa074137     00000002`fffe6060     000007fe`f8e31860    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+20c91f     00000003`ffc41ef8     00000004`0313cef8     00000004`0313e5a0     00000004`015e1ef0    
0x000007fe`9a8597e7     00000002`fffe4a28     000007fe`f2137f69     000007fe`9a811e88     000007fe`f1ed0a23    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+b2ce1     000007fe`9a811e88     000007fe`f1ed082d     00000001`ffd15c14     00000003`00023c74    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+a0c3c     00000000`00000000     00000003`00023cb0     00000004`015e1ef0     00000000`0e6cd760    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+1fbd92     00000001`ffd8f520     000007fe`f76e5277     00000004`0313cef8     000007fe`f0e81779    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+1fc626     00000003`027f98f8     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+a0715     00000001`ffd8f508     00000004`015e2018     00000004`0313cef8     00000004`015e2080    
System_Runtime_Serialization_ni+a03f5     00000000`00000066     000007fe`f1ee66fc     00000000`00000065     00000000`00000000    
System_ServiceModel_ni+5eaf06     00000004`015e1ef0     00000002`fffe2158     00000002`fffe4908     000007fe`f1ec1577    
System_ServiceModel_ni+5eade9     00000001`00000064     00000003`ffb31420     00000001`ffd06138     00000001`ffd06138    
System_ServiceModel_ni+5eac97     00000000`00000000     00000004`0000000e     00000004`015e1ef0     00000004`015e1ef0    
System_ServiceModel_ni+5eab05     00000004`015e1e88     00000003`0000bd68     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    
System_ServiceModel_ni+650ed8     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000001`ffbcf838     00000000`00000000    
System_ServiceModel_ni+650b93     00000000`0e6cdd20     00000004`015e1de8     00000001`ffec0ef0     00000004`0313d388    
System_ServiceModel_ni+635c07     00000000`0e6cde30     00000001`ffbf92b0     00000004`0313d308     000007fe`7fffffff    
0x000007fe`9a6a601c     00000001`ffbcb2f0     000007fe`ef84b555     00000003`04f95618     00000004`0313d488    
System_ServiceModel_ni+5f316c     00000000`0e6ce060     00000000`00000001     00000000`0e6ce060     000007fe`f4ff80f3    
System_ServiceModel_ni+5f2c8e     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000003`04f956c0    
System_ServiceModel_ni+62380a     00000000`0e6ce000     00000003`054831d0     01ceb097`e03b5200     00000000`00000000    
System_ServiceModel_ni+6232d1     00000000`00000000     00000004`0313d308     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    
System_ServiceModel_ni+618d4b     00000003`04f95618     00000004`0313d308     00000000`23c34600     00000000`00000000    
System_ServiceModel_ni+618bf3     00000003`0000c190     00000000`0e6ce820     00000003`0000c190     00000001`ffbd7038    
System_ServiceModel_ni+6189ad     00000003`0000c190     00000000`0e6ce820     00000000`00000000     000007fe`f9d5d900    
System_ServiceModel_ni+617a2a     00000003`0000c190     00000000`0e6ce820     000007fe`9a7857b8     00000000`0e6ce820    
System_ServiceModel_ni+6124c6     00000003`0000c190     00000000`0e6ce820     00006a2a`00000000     00000000`0f48e8a0    
System_ServiceModel_ni+611b2b     00000003`000299c8     000007fe`f5f1d74b     00000001`ffbf9d28     00000000`00000000    
System_ServiceModel_ni+61053e     00000000`0e6ce820     000007fe`f1ed0d00     00000000`00000000     000007fe`f8621f10    
System_ServiceModel_ni+60fa57     00000000`ffb46740     00000003`04f95618     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    
System_ServiceModel_ni+60de03     00000003`ffc0fb60     00000001`ffbf92b0     80000000`00000000     00000003`000296d0    
System_ServiceModel_ni+60d92b     00000000`00000000     000007fe`f9e33824     00000000`0122f070     00000000`00000000    
System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+4c352     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000003`054834a0     00000000`0e6cec18    
System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+47d2a     00000004`04299c58     000007fe`f76ef200     00000000`00000000     00000000`0e6ceca0    
System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+4c5f1     00000000`0e6cec20     00000003`04f95890     00000003`04f96060     000007fe`f56a4c65    
System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+4c1cc     00000000`ffb465a0     00000000`0e6cedf0     00000003`05450001     000007fe`f5efdda6    
System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+4bd9e     00000001`ffbf9620     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    
System_ServiceModel_ni+622eb2     00000003`04f95890     00000003`05451a10     00000003`04f957b0     00000003`04f95890    
System_ServiceModel_ni+62281f     00000001`ffbf9620     00000003`04f95790     00000003`04f957b0     00000003`04f95780    
System_ServiceModel_ni+62268a     00000003`04f95890     000007fe`f4f9b001     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    
System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+e93f8     00000003`04f95618     000007fe`f56d0e96     00000003`04f95550     000007fe`f9cc5699    
System_ServiceModel_ni+621582     00000001`ffbf9620     00000003`04f95618     00000000`00000001     00000003`04f956d8    
System_ServiceModel_ni+620c38     00000003`04f956d8     00000003`ffc0f940     00000001`01d742a8     000007fe`ef858cb0    
System_ServiceModel_ni+620a2a     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000003`ffc0fb60     00000003`04f949b8    
System_ServiceModel_Activation_ni+71d48     00000002`00040004     00000001`02b1f848     00000003`04f953a8     000007fe`9a7aad00    
System_ServiceModel_Activation_ni+6ac44     00000001`01d742a8     00000001`ffb3a450     00000000`0e6cf608     00000000`00000000    
System_ServiceModel_Activation_ni+6ae35     00000001`0173afd8     000007fe`f8617fd7     00000000`0e6cf280     00000000`00000000    
System_ServiceModel_Activation_ni+6aec3     00000003`ffc0daf0     00000000`00000000     00000003`04f94528     000007fe`ef84c79c    
System_ServiceModel_Activation_ni+2c7a2     00000001`ffb3a498     00000001`ffb384a8     00000000`d2d6d2d7     000007fe`f4f9e809    
System_ServiceModel_Activation_ni+6afe3     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    
System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+4e651     00000000`0e6cf4c0     000007fe`fa0bb84b     00000000`0f48e8a0     00000000`00000002    
System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni+4e5d0     00000000`0e6cf550     00000000`0e6cf470     00000000`0e6cf5e0     00000001`ffb384c8    
mscorlib_ni+534fa6     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000001`ffb3a498     00000000`11dc0470    
clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+83     00000000`10b0ec30     00000000`11f43e20     00000000`001d0000     00000000`00000468    
clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+4a     00000000`00000000     00000000`0e6cf5e0     00000000`0e6cf608     000007fe`f854af18    
clr!DispatchCallSimple+85     00000000`0e6cfca0     00000001`ffb3a498     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    
clr!BindIoCompletionCallBack_Worker+b8     00000001`ffb3a450     00000000`0e6cfc10     00000000`0e6cfcc0     00000000`0e6cfc10    
clr!DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame::DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame+a0     00000000`0e6cfc10     00000000`00000000     00000000`120a12f8     000007fe`ecad6585    
clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+38e     00000000`ffffffff     000007fe`f9c63108     00000000`0f48e8a0     000007fe`f9c63108    
clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+2bd     00000000`0e6cf9b8     00000000`0f48e8a0     00000000`0e6cfc10     00000000`0f48e8a0    
clr!ReturnToPreviousAppDomainHolder::Init+39     00000000`00000000     00000000`023e0340     00000000`0e6cfcc0     00000000`0e6cfcc0    
clr!Thread::DoADCallBack+234     00000000`00000002     00000000`00000002     00000000`0e6cfc10     00000000`0e6cfc10    
clr!DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame::DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame+d6     00000000`0e6cfc10     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000030     00000000`120a0000    
clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+38e     00000000`80004005     00000000`0e6cfc40     000007fe`fa324dd8     00000000`0f48e8a0    
clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+2bd     80000000`00000000     00000000`0f48e8a0     00000000`0f48e8a0     00000000`00000000    
clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+23b     00000000`00000002     00000000`0e6cfcf0     00000000`00008000     000007fe`fd5216ad    
clr!BindIoCompletionCallbackStubEx+cd     00000001`00040004     00000000`00000001     00000000`0f48e8a0     00000001`00000001    
clr!BindIoCompletionCallbackStub+9     00000002`00040004     00000002`00040004     00000000`00000001     00000000`00000000    
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CompletionPortThreadStart+361     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000001     00000000`00000000    
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+7d     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+d     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+1d     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000    

Exception Information
CLR!GETRUNTIMEASSEMBLYHELPER+1DIn WER45CE.tmp.mdmp the assembly instruction at clr!GetRuntimeAssemblyHelper+1d in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused a stack overflow exception (0xC00000FD) when trying to write to memory location 0x0e655ff8 on thread 49
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but did you check the event viewer? I had my w3wp.exe crashing because of a stack overflow... no pun intended. But I was able to find the cause in the event viewer.

Comment: Phil, this info in post (top portion) IS from event viewer. And yes, this is stack overflow. But I don't see enough details to understand what causing it.

Comment: Your next best bet is to start running the site in VS in debug mode.. sometimes, VS will show you more info. Even better is to put a bunch of break points in... line by line until you find it. It sucks, but sometimes that is needed.

Comment: Sounds like a serialization issue - are you serializing any complex types or objects that have a lot of nested types in them?  If so, are there any potentially obvious culprits that you could start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The details in the event log does point out to a serialization problem, however I don't recall serialization problems causing the w3wp to crash.
First of all, turn on WCF tracing to get the WCF logs and see the exact serialization issue (if that is the case).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Second, regarding fail-over, if an application pool crashes it will automatically restart itself. However, if after a restart the pool crashes again, several times during a given period (5 crashed during 5 minutes is the default) the application pool will be stopped to prevent more crashes - this should have an indication in the event log.

As for the serialization issue - if you can't figure out the issue from the trace, can you possibly publish the xml content here? or upload it somewhere and provide a link? If you are using an HTTP binding you can simply open Fiddler and copy the request content. If you are using TCP or other bindings, you can use the WCF Message Logging to log the message (don't forget to set LogEntireMessage to true). 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx

Comment: Problem is - there was no crashes since I posted this. I even wonder if it's hackers attack because system is under constant load and can run for days. Crashed 3 or 4 times already in a month. And yes, it was 5 crashes in 5 minutes setting which I bumped to avoid stop. I also run debugger now to take snapshot. Currently memory dump I showed in original post is all I have

Answer (score 0):

There is a hotfix out to potentially fix the stack overflow:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640103

```
Is there any way to monitor service and restart in case of such crash inside IIS?
```

Have you tried turning off Rapid Fail Protection in IIS? Rapid failure protection will stop your w3p service if concurrent failures happen within the specified interval. see http://www.iisunderground.com/disable-rapid-fail-protection/

Causes:

```
A worker process does not start within the startup time limit.

A worker process does not shut down within the shutdown time limit.

A worker process shuts itself down because of a fatal error and sends the WWW service an error code.

A worker process fails to respond to a ping message.

The WWW service detects that a worker process is sending non-standard communications (the worker process may have been taken over).
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up diagnostics in config file?

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue ="Critical, Error"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "c:\logs\servicelog.e2e" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

You need to add permission to service to write to C:\logs or whichever folder you select. This has helped me many times to get low level stack information on which method has exception occured.

Answer (score 0):

You have the 64bit version of the framework on the server, was the app developed on a 32 bit system then deployed?

If yes, re build app on 64 bit system then re deploy.

Also any 3rd party dll's you have refererenced in your app, you may need to aquire thier 64bit equivalents

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a similar issue. In my case I had added aspNetCompatibilityEnabled=”true” to my web.config and I was running in asp.net 2.0 compatibility mode. This KB article describes the problem in more detail

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/977104